Number of subsets with even intersection
Suppose we have $m$ subsets of a 10-element set, each subset has odd size, all intersections of these subsets have even size. Find maximum possible value of $m$.
My first (and unfortunately the last) observation:
Let's fix some set $A$, and let's notice that there can not be any subsets inside of the $A$ set (because their intersection would have odd size). Unfortunately I got no idea what to do next and how to approach this task

You posted the same question a few minutes ago, it was closed for lack of effort.

Some natural places to start:  solve the problem for smaller sets than order $10$.  Or:  Get lower bounds on $m$.  What's the biggest good collection you can think of?  Try to expand it or show that it is actually maximal.

@lulu, you can not take $B = {1, 2}$ because all sets should be odd and B set has even cardinality

Agreed, I noticed that and already deleted that comment.

Encode subsets as binary vectors of $10$ entries; $1$ means that the corresponding element is in the subset and $0$ means that it is not. If you take two of those vectors $u=(u_1,...,u_{10})$ and $v=(v_1,...,v_{10})$, corresponding to two different sets, their dot product $u\cdot v=u_1v_1+...+u_{10}v_{10}$, computed in binary, gives the parity of the intersection of the corresponding sets. Observe also that since the sizes of the sets are odd, then $u\cdot u=1$.

This problem(s) is known as "oddtown eventown problem". Googling that you can find many places talking about it(them), like this one

@ameg, thanks for this idea with encoding, but how can we use it to find maximum value of m?

Linear algebra. The vectors must be linearly independent, since their dot-product condition shows that they are orthogonal to each other. Therefore, cannot be more than the dimension, $10$. Finding examples with $10$ can be done by considering all single element sets, or all $9$ element sets.

In the link above they have a proof that is made to look as not using linear algebra. So, it is a combinatorial proof.
